# Best way to automate an mobile internet data package assignment for company users

Tags: java, python, selenium, automation

I'm new and learning so please bear with me :)

I work in the helpdesk department at this place and we get daily data package requests. The package can be 1 or 3 Gb and has an set date to start from. I have tries selenium with python and I have only been getting errors and compatibility issues. What programming language would you use to do this task.

1-Get email with users name, phone number, type of package (private,work), and if its 1 or 3GB

2-Script gets the data updated from the email to each user

2-Start the script that logins into the webpage, chooses the package 1 or 3 GB, and the start date.

3- Takes a screenshot if there exists an package for the user already and send this to our helpdesk mailbox

4- maybe more

All the advice will be appreciated

Comment: help with what? so far all you've done is posted (incomplete) requirements.

Comment: What programming language would you use to do this task.

Comment: Maybe more? Incldues what?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

> Many, perhaps most, software applications today are written as
>   web-based applications to be run in an Internet browser. The
>   effectiveness of testing these applications varies widely among
>   companies and organizations. In an era of highly interactive and
>   responsive software processes where many organizations are using some
>   form of Agile methodology, test automation is frequently becoming a
>   requirement for software projects. Test automation is often the
>   answer. Test automation means using a software tool to run repeatable
>   tests against the application to be tested. For regression testing
>   this provides that responsiveness.
>
> There are many advantages to test automation. Most are related to the
>   repeatability of the tests and the speed at which the tests can be
>   executed. There are a number of commercial and open source tools
>   available for assisting with the development of test automation.
>   Selenium is possibly the most widely-used open source solution. This
>   user’s guide will assist both new and experienced Selenium users in
>   learning effective techniques in building test automation for web
>   applications.

As Per selenium official site, you can see

Selenium-WebDriver supports the following browsers along with the operating systems these browsers are compatible with.

- Firefox: latest ESR, previous ESR, current release, one previous
  release
- Safari
- Opera
- HtmlUnit
- phantomjs
- Android (with Selendroid or appium)
- iOS (with ios-driver or appium)

Browsers which supports

- Firefox 3.x,3,2
- IE 8,7,6
- Safari 4,3,2
- Opera 10,9,8
- Google Chrome

The Technology which supports selenium are

- Java
- C#
- Ruby
- Python
- Javascript (Node)
- PHP